# Derivatives of symmetric expressions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials

So I was bored in math class and came up with this series of related questions, that I cannot answer:

Is there a clean expression for $f'(x),$ where $$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{(x-i)}{(x+i)}?$$

What about for $f''(x)?$ Or for $$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{(x^2-i)}{(x^2+i)}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as BRIC-Fan answered, logarithmic differentiation is extremely convenient. Suppose $$F=\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$$ So $$\log(F)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(f_i(x))$$so $$\frac{F'}{F}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f'_i(x)}{f_i(x)}$$ and so $$F'=F\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f'_i(x)}{f_i(x)}$$ Now, for the second derivative $$F''=F'\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f'_i(x)}{f_i(x)}+F\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f''_i(x)f_i(x)-f'(x)^2}{f_i(x)^2}$$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: Take $\log f(x)$ and then differentiate it !